# Are there some good algorithm to select m by three matrices which satisfies certain conditions?

Tags: algorithms

I would like to find an algorithm which select matrices satisfying certain conditions.

We consider integer matrices (entries of the matrices comes from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some positive integer $n$) and the numbers in each row are different from each other.

Let me first explain some definitions.

We call a matrix $M$ with m rows and k columns canonical if for all $i \in [2, m]$ and $j \in [2, k]$, $M_{i,j} > M_{i-1, j-1}$ and for all $i \in [2,m]$ and $j \in [1,k]$, $a_{ij} \ge a_{i-1,j}$. For example, $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}3 & 5 & 9\\2 & 5 & 8\\1 & 4 & 7\\1 & 4 & 6\end{array}\right)$ is canonical.

Let $M$ be a matrix with $k$ columns. Denote by $I_j$ the set of the elements in the $j$th row. We say that two rows $j_1, j_2$ of $M$ i-interlacing if $|J_{j_1} \backslash J_{j_2}|=|J_{j_2} \backslash J_{j_1}|=i$ and $J_{j_1}\backslash J_{j_2} = \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i\}$, $J_{j_2} \backslash J_{j_1} = \{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_i\}$, either $a_1 < b_1<a_2<b_2 < \cdots < b_{i-1} <a_i < b_i$ or $b_1<a_1<b_2<a_2 < \ldots < a_{i-1}<b_i<a_i$. In particular, if two rows of a matrix are identical, then we say that the two rows are $0$-interlacing.

For example, the first row and the second row of $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}3 & 5 & 9\\2 & 5 & 8\\1 & 4 & 7\\1 & 4 & 6\end{array}\right)$ are $2$-interlacing. The third row and the fourth row of the matrix are $1$-interlacing.

For a matrix $M$ with entries in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, denote $x=x(M)=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, where $x_i$ is the number of entries in $M$ which equal to $i$. Denote $q(M)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \frac{2-k}{k^2} (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2$, where $k$ is the number of columns of $M$. For example, let $M=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}3 & 5 & 9\\2 & 5 & 8\\1 & 4 & 7\\1 & 4 & 6\end{array}\right)$. Then $x(M) = (2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1)$ and $q(M)=2$.

I would like to find all $m \times 3$ matrices $M$ with entries in $\{1, \ldots, 9\}$ which satisfy the following conditions:

(1) in each row of $M$, any two entries are different from each other; the numbers in each row are increasing from left to right;

(2) any two rows of $M$ are $i$-interlacing for some $i \in \{0,1,2,3\}$;

(3) there are two rows of $M$ which are $3$-interlacing;

(4) $M$ is canonical;

(5) $q(M)=2$.

In the cases of $m=2,3,4$, I use many for loops to find out all such matrices. But when $m \ge 5$, it takes infinite time. Is there some fast algorithm to find out all the matrices which satisfy the conditions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to deal with this problem—which perhaps can hardly be called a "good algorithm", but nonetheless provides a variety of performance improvements—is to treat it as a constraint satisfaction / combinatorial search problem and apply backtracking. Each matrix entry branches the search tree 9 ways, but many of these subtrees can be trivially eliminated because they immediately violate one of the conditions.

Take the $m = 5$ case that you got stuck on as an example. For condition 1, note that already there are only $\binom{9}{3}^5 = 4,182,119,424$ matrices of size 5x3 with elements in [1..9] which have elements strictly increasing from left to right in each row. It's $\binom{9}{3}^5$ because condition 1 is equivalent to, for each row, choosing 3 distinct elements from [1..9]. You can of course iterate over such rows with

`for i in 1 to 7, for j in i + 1 to 8, for k in j + 1 to 9`

Moreover, conditions 2 and 4 can be checked as you are generating the rows, rather than only checking these conditions once you have the entire matrix. This should drastically prune the search tree.

[Tassle](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/108026/tassle) adds (and provides [this sample code](https://pastebin.com/qPzS3tVw)):

> You can also prune on condition (5) by first computing all possible profiles $x(M)$ which lead to $q(M)=2$, and then trying to find all satisfying matrices with a specific profile. Out of all 490314 ways to choose 15 numbers in {1...9}, only 84 lead to $q(M)=2$. In fact, using this, even python on my quite slow machine can manage m = 5 in a reasonable time.

This sort of brute forcing is also [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) and requires hardly any memory, so consider dividing the space of matrices among however many CPU cores you have.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative algorithm to enumerate such matrices, which proceeds by induction on $m$.  I suspect it will be be better than brute force.

Let condition (2') be that every pair of rows is $i$-interlacing for some $i\in \{0,1,2\}$.

Note that every matrix that satisfies conditions (1), (2), (3), (4) can be broken up into the concatenation of a matrix $M^1$ that satisfies conditions (1), (2'), (4), a row $r^2$ that when paired with some row of $M^1$ is 3-interleaving, and a matrix $M^3$ that satisfies conditions (1), (2'), (4).  So, we will enumerate all $M^1,r^2,M^3$ and look at their combinations.  We'll do it in a smart way that ensures that their concatenation satisfies conditions (4), (5).

Write $r\prec r'$ if row $r$ can precede row $r'$ in a canonical matrix, i.e., $r_0<r'_1$ and $r_1<r'_2$.  Write $q(x) = \sum_{i=1}^9 x_i^2 - 1/9 (\sum_{i=1}^9 x_i)^2$.

By induction, assume we have a data structure that lists all $m' \times 3$ matrices that satisfy conditions (1), (2'), (4), for all $m'<m$.  Arrange the data structure as a hashtable of lists, keyed on the value of $(m',x(M),M_m')$, where $M_m'$ denotes the last row of the matrix; looking $(m',x,r)$ up in the hashtable returns a list of all $m'\times 3$ matrices $M$ such that $x(M)=x$, $M_m'=r$, and $M$ satisfies conditions (1), (2'), (4).

Similarly, assume we have a data structure that lists all $m'\times 3$ matrices that satisfy conditions (1), (2'), (4), for all $m'<m$, keyed on the value of $(m',x(M),M_1)$, where $M_1$ denotes the first row of the matrix.

Now, enumerate all $m^1,x^1,r^1,r^2,m^3,x^3,r^3$ such that $m^1,x^1,r^1$ that is a valid key of the first hashtable, $r^1 \prec r^2 \prec r^3$, $m^3,x^3,r^3$ is a valid key of the second hashtable, $m^1+1+m^3=m$, and $q(x^1+x(r^2)+x^3)=2$.  Then every way of pairing a matrix $M^1$ from the first hashtable (keyed on $(m^1,x^1,r^1)$), the row $r^2$, and a matrix $M^3$ from the second hashtable (keyed on $(m^3,x^3,r^3)$) will yield a matrix $M$ (obtained by concatenating $M^1,r^2,M^3$) that satisfies conditions (1)-(5).

To do this enumeration, I suggest you first guess $r^1,r^2,r^3$ such that $r^1\prec r^2 \prec r^3$, then guess $m^1,m^3$ such that $m^1+1+m^3=m$, then enumerate all $x^1$ such that $m^1,x^1,r^1$ appears as a key of the hashtable, then enumerate all $x^3$ such that $q(x^1+x(r^3)+x^3)=2$ and check whether $m^3,x^3,r^3$ is a key in the hashtable.  However you can also try other orders of enumeration.

Also, enumerate all $m^1,x^1,r^1,m^3,x^3,r^3$ such that $m^1,x^1,r^1$ that is a valid key of the first hashtable, $r_1 \prec r^3$, $m^3,x^3,r^3$ is a valid key of the second hashtable, and $m^1+m^3=m$; this gives a $m\times 3$ matrix (obtained by a concatenating $M^1$ and $M^3$) that satisfies conditions (1), (2'), (4).  This lets you build up the data structure inductively for $m$ from the data structures for $1,\dots,m-1$.

Further optimization may be possible.  The condition $q(M)=2$ is a fairly strong one.  For instance, for $m=5$, it implies that $x$ is a permutation of $(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)$.  It implies $\sum_i x_i^2=m^2+2$, and we also know $\sum_i x_i=3m$.  This may be helpful for pruning entries of the data structures, when you know $m$ in advance.  For instance, if you know that you only care about $m \le 5$, then you can prune all $x(M)$ that contain 3 or any larger number.

Note also that if you care only about *counting* the number of such matrices, this algorithm gives a way of counting them that may be more efficient than enumerating them.  There is no need to store the entire list of such matrices; you can simply store the number of such matrices corresponding to each key in the hashtable.